# How to edit a microsoft window spacing from a java application?

Tags: java, ms-word

i'm trying to implement  steganography's word shifting coding protocol on a microsoft word report using java application. Basicly, it uses an existing report and edit it's spacing to put some secret data. If it's wider, then its 1 bit data. And if it's narrower, then it's 0 bit data. So i wonder what kind of library should i have to start constructing this java app or if java doesn't support this kind of comunication with ms-word what kind language of programming should i use, thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using C# and the [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.aspx). You can use the free Visual Studio Community version (https://www.visualstudio.com/products/visual-studio-community-vs), create a console application and add a reference for the interop namespace (in project explorer, right click on references, add reference: COM->Microsoft Word 16.0 Object Library).

Simple example:

```
namespace WordShiftingExample
{
    class Program
    {

        private static int[] getSpaces(string text)
        {
            System.Collections.ArrayList list = new System.Collections.ArrayList();
            int index = 0;

            while (index != text.LastIndexOf(" "))
            {
                index = text.IndexOf(" ", index + 1);
                list.Add(index);
            }
            return list.ToArray(typeof(int)) as int[];
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application winword = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
                winword.ShowAnimation = false;
                winword.Visible = false;
                object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document document = winword.Documents.Add(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);

                float zero = 0.1F;
                float one = 0.15F;

                document.Content.Text = "This is a test document.";

                //set word-spacing for first two spaces
                int[] spaces = getSpaces(document.Content.Text);

                document.Range(spaces[0], spaces[0]+1).Font.Spacing=zero;
                document.Range(spaces[1], spaces[1]+1).Font.Spacing = one;

                //read word-spacing  for first two spaces
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(document.Range(spaces[0], spaces[0]+1).Font.Spacing); // prints 0.1
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(document.Range(spaces[1], spaces[1]+1).Font.Spacing); // prints 0.15

                //Save the document
                object filename = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USERPROFILE")+"\\temp1.docx";
                document.SaveAs2(ref filename);
                document.Close(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
                document = null;
                winword.Quit(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
                winword = null;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
            }
        }
    }
}
```